# Secure FTP using private key authentication

Tags: java, uri, sftp, private-key

I am using JSCH library to do a sftp between two servers. But, I am unable to load the file into the `URL` using `getResource()`, for which I get an error during runtime. I checked the permissions and they are 600, so we should be able to read it.

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    File file = new File("/home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa");
    Session session = null;
    URL keyFileURL = null;
    URI keyFileURI = null;
    if (file.exists())
    {
        keyFileURL = SecureFTP.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa");
        if (keyFileURL == null)
        {
            System.out.println("what");
            throw new RuntimeException("Key file not found in classpath");
        }
    }
  try{
             keyFileURI = keyFileURL.toURI();
    }
    catch(Exception URISyntaxException)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong URL. LOL");
}



    jsch.addIdentity(new File(keyFileURI).getAbsolutePath());
```

Is there something I am missing, in loading the resource or the path?

Comment: which file? the key file? the program compiles fine, it gives me an error during runtime.

Comment: Is /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa on the classpath? Should it be? It looks like you want to get a file under your "/home" dir. I do not think that would be a resource of your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the [`File.toURL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURL%28%29)

```
File file = new File("/home/dev85adm/.ssh/id_rsa");
if (file.exists()) {
    URL keyFileURL = file.toURL();
    //...
```

Comment: this helped, but now I am getting an auth fail, which is unrelated. Thanks.